# Do combining epic/legendary skin shards increase chances of getting better skin shards?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have several Epic and Legendary skin shards. Do combining them increase my chances of getting a other Epic or Legendary skin shards?

Comment: Don't think there's any information on the chances. but it's verified that combining 3 legendaries, doesn't result in a legendary skin. So it's unlikely.